# Filter divs depending on numeric quantity entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to set up a filter using jQuery. I'll have a certain amount of `div`s, each with a numeric value (let's say price).

I want to have a textbox and button that filters out any `div`s that are higher than the value given. So for instance, if I enter `10` and hit filter, all divs with a numeric value of 10 or above are hidden.

I can only find filter scripts that are executed via buttons [like this](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/196_jquery/index.htm), but none of those use a numeric value.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please bear in mind that my JavaScript skills are limited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/SMPAq/1/

UPDATE:

Ok, here is the whole thing:

```
<script>
function sortmebaby()
{
    var divList = $('#containerMonkey div[id^="monkey_"]');  

$.each(divList, function(index, value)
{
    console.log($(value).attr('xprice'));
    if ( $(value).attr('xprice') > $('#mankipower').val())
        $(value).hide();
    else
        $(value).show();
    //alert(index + ': ' + value);
});

}
</script>

<div id="containerMonkey">
    <div id="monkey_1" xprice="1">1</div>
    <div id="monkey_2" xprice="2">2</div>
    <div id="monkey_3" xprice="3">3</div>
    <div id="monkey_4" xprice="4">4</div>
    <div id="monkey_5" xprice="5">5</div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="mankipower" id="mankipower">
<input type="button" value="PUSH" onclick="sortmebaby()">
```

Comment: Please post your answer here as well as just providing a fiddle. If the link expires for any reason your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Any way to make the results fade in and out? :)

Comment: replace hide() and show() to fadeOut() and fadeIn() respectively.
http://jsfiddle.net/SMPAq/2/

Comment: Oops, there seems to be a bug...

I've changed the xprice="1" values to 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50, and the filter seems to show some erratic results?

Comment: @GrahamMcDonnell, my answer works for all cases, if you notice the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this, iterate thru the each `div` that has a `class` of `prices`
Get the value, parse it as an `int`, compare it to `textbox` with the `id` of `myTextBox`

```
$('div.prices').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text());
    if (value >= parseInt($('#myTextBox').val()))
       $(this).hide();
    else 
       $(this).show();
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKJW6/3/)

Comment: Is there anyway to have this so it includes the value you enter? For example, if I enter 12 on your example I get everything under 12 and not 12 itself.

Also, I wouldn't want the value to actually be visible to the users in the div, rather just a value in the code if possible?

Comment: Yes, just change the `if` statement to be `if (value > parseInt($('#myTextBox').val()))` .. which i just remvoed the greater than of equal too and just made it greater than

Comment: Brilliant. And how about the hidden value thing? I wouldn't want the value to actually be visible to the users in the div, rather just a value in the code if possible?

Comment: Just change the `textbox` to a `hidden` element then. `<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField"/>`

Comment: I see you already marked the other answer as the solution, maybe you should reconsider.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the value that a div has is not viewable by the user, not the value that is entered into the text box. Like the xprice="1" on the first solution. This has already been solved elsewhere though, thanks for trying.

Comment: Hide the container of divs with css. `display: none`